# InApp Browser phoneGap for IOS will not load pages from a local server

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

Here is the Code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function open_win()
{
window.open(encodeURI("<inserturlhere>"))
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="open_win()">
</body>
</html>
```

It works for other websites like google, apache.

I have given access to all domains in the config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing semicolon (**;**) at the end of the window.open if it is written by mistake then try the below code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var ref=null;

      function iabLoadStart(event) {
         console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
      }

      function iabLoadStop(event) {
         console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
      }

      function iabClose(event) {
         console.log(event.type);
         ref.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         ref.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
      }

      function open_win() {
         ref=window.open(encodeURI("<inserturlhere>"),'_blank', 'location=no');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         ref.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="open_win()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean local files that are served from the filesystem? Ie. file:// instead of http://? In that case I think this is a bug with the current Phonegap version.

I have been using this as a workaround (opening an inappbrowser instance):

```
// Image zoom
$('#container').on('tap', '#content.cmscontent img', function() {
    var browser = window.open((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ? 'file:///android_asset/www/' : '') + encodeURI($(this).attr('src')), '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=yes,enableViewportScale=yes,transitionstyle=crossdissolve');
});
```

See I added `(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ? 'file:///android_asset/www/' : '')` as a prefix before the url. Now it detects when you're app is on Android and adds the local URL in front of it.